# kubernetes session affinity behavior

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb

I am using kubernetes 1.9.2 created but kubeadm.
this kubernetes cluster is running in 4 ec2 nodes.

I have a deployment that requires using cache in every pod.
in order to accomlish that we used session affinity from ClusterIP.

since I was ELB in front of my Kubernetes cluster I wonder how the session affinity is behaving.

the natural behavior would be that for every client IP a different will get the requests but given the traffic is transferred via ELB , whoch IP does the session affinity recognizes , the ELB IP or the actual Client IP?

when I check the traffic to the pods I see that 102 pods get all the requests and the 2 other pods are just waiting.

many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SessionAffinity` recognizes Client IP and ELB should pass the Client IP.

I think you should work with [HTTP Headers and Classic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html) and setup `X-Forwarded-For: client-ip-address`

Also, this seems to be a know issue [enabling Session affinity goes to a single pod only #3056](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3056).

It was reported for `0.18.0` and `0.19.0` version of NGINX Ingress controller.

Issue was closed and commented that is was fixed in version `0.21.0`, but in December initial author said it still doesn't work for him.